# Caliburn.Micro 2.0 and IViewAware Implementation Issue

Tags: mvvm, caliburn.micro

This question can probably only be answered by a CM contributor.

`ViewAware` is a base implementation of `IViewAware` which uses an internal utility class `WeakValueDictionary` for caching views. External implementors of `IViewAware` cannot access this class.

CM 1.5.x relied upon `Dictionary<object, object>` for its caching implementation.

I cannot see in code any dependency in CM 2.0 which requires the use of `WeakValueDictionary` when implementing `IViewAware`.

I just want to make sure I am not missing something subtle? Do I have to use `WeakValueDictionary` when implementing `IViewAware`, or is `Dictionary<object, object>` still sufficient?

Comment: I believe it was a result of viewcacheing and being able to disable it in some use cases as well as the availability in other platforms (wp/Silverlight) to go with the WeakValueDirectionary. There was a rather lengthy thread on the old codeplex site discussions about it.  They wanted to have something that would prevent the possibility of memory leaks.  There was a ticket opened and closed with specifics related to the change w/ the incorporation into CM2.0

Comment: Appreciate the context. Don't suppose you know the answer to whether one can still use Dictionary<object, object> when implementing IViewAware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary<object, object>` can be ok, as long as you're diligent in managing your views. `IViewAware` doesn't have a way to clear the view. In the built in classes `Screen` cleans the view up on `Deactivate` which should happen as long as you're composing your view models together well.

Using `WeakValueDictionary` gives us some wriggle room that means we're not holding on to views that aren't used any more.

We could certainly consider making `WeakValueDictionary` available to help with this.